# Create SQL Server table from XML Schema or from XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Is there a way to create tables in sql server from a xml file or xml schema? I would like to create table for each parent element in the xml item. The problem is that I have a XML file that can reach more than 2000 itens and to create a table for each of the elements of the file would take a long time.